# Landing page for variant

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to have different landing pages for each variants?

E.g.

https://store-w40xoh.mybigcommerce.com/chanel-the-cheetah/?sku=SKU-F4180933 - this one should have preset size M

https://store-w40xoh.mybigcommerce.com/chanel-the-cheetah/?sku=SKU-1A86555B - this one should have preset size S

Comment: Yep, it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the jQuery code below. Basically it loads the `sku` querystring parameter as the condition for the `switch` statement, with the specific SKUs entered case by case. From there, if the SKU in the QueryString matches one in the `case`, it will attempt to physically `click` the relevant option.

Looking at the page source, I've concluded the following association between Size and `input` Value: 
`XS = 68` 
`S  = 69` 
`M  = 70` 
`L  = 71` 
`XL = 72`

```js
<script>

  // On DOM Ready:
  $(function() {
    switch ($.urlParam('sku')) {
      case 'SKU-F4180933':
        // Set Size to M
        $("input[value='70']").click();
        break;
      case 'SKU-1A86555B':
        // Set Size to S
        $("input[value='69']").click();
        break;
    }
  });

  /**
   * Gets a URL parameter by name.
   * @param name <string> - The name of the URL parameter to get. 
   * @return <string|bool> - The value of the URL parameter, or false on fail.
   */
  $.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '= ([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null) {
     return false;
    } else {
     return results[1] || false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is untested, so I can't guarantee that it will work. Hope it gives the basic idea though. /

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch the request URL and retrieve sku id. You can use the SKU id to customize your page.

I had a similar requirement to configure the landing page based on request URL so we used [www.grooveui.com](https://www.grooveui.com) Using this tool also, you can set landing page based on query params, domains or sub-domains.